# MtGox Gem Failing to Login

Tags: ruby, bitcoin

I am trying to use the MtGox gem to cancel orders, however, I only get the following error message:

```
{"error":"Must be logged in"}
```

I am using the following code to make the call:

```
MtGox.configure {|c| c.key = user.mtgox_key; c.secret = user.mtgox_secret}
MtGox.cancel('oid'=>'a3c348d9-36c3-4927-b84d-206f421907f5', 'type'=>1)
```

I have also tried getting all of the open orders for a specific user using the following:

```
MtGox.post('/api/0/getOrders.php', {})
```

Alas, every call returns the same error message.  Am I missing something?

Comment: FYI: I just (5 minutes ago) got the same error on the mtgox website itself, while placing an order. It might be MtGox's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by using a smaller nonce for v1 api calls.  Interestingly, a nonce of length 22 was causing subsequent v0 api calls to fail, but not subsequent v1 calls.  I compute my nonce by simply using:

```
var nonce = ((new Date()).getTime()*1000).toString(); // microseconds since epoch
```